# Android error "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an `AsyncTask` with a `ProgressDialog` to show the progress. The problem is that I cannot set the `ProgressDialog Max` value until the `doInBackground` method (I need to do some calculations), I cannot set it in the `onPreExecute` method because I do not know the value yet.

I'm getting this error because obviously I'm trying to modify the `UI` from a background `Thread`.

`Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`
I initialise the `ProgressDialog` in the `AsyncTask` constructor:

```
public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.wait_for_sync_title));
    progressDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.please_wait));
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
}
```

I show it in the `onPreExecute` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

I need to update the `ProgressDialog` in the `doInBackground` method:

```
@Override
protected void doInBackground() {
    progressDialog.setMax(myValue1);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    publishProgress(myValue2);
}
```

Here the `onProgressUpdate` method:

```
 @Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
}
```

And finally, I dismiss it in the `onPostExecute` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
    if(progressDialog != null) {
       progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I've tried this inside the `thread` method, but I cannot do it in the `AsyncTask` since `runOnUiThread` is a method for `Activity`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      progressDialog.setMax(myValue1);
      progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
   }
});
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: show Progress Dialog on `OnProgressUpdate` method

Comment: where are you getting myValue1 from? It seems that you are just calling it as soon as the task starts but there is no indication where the value is retrieved from

Comment: I'm paginating a `Network Request` so I don't know how many `requests` I have until the `doInBackground` method. What I want to display in the `progressDialog.setMax()` method is the numbers of `request`

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand me or maybe the code you have posted is not complete. The very first thing you do in the task is to set the Max value so you must have that value before you start the task. Just set it before you execute the AsyncTask

Comment: May I know the reason of the down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `Handler` of main thread and post it there as below

```
@Override protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
      progressDialog.setMax(myValue1);
      progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    }
  });
  publishProgress(myValue2);
}
```

The above method is same as calling `runOnUiTHread()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest simply making your progress value a pair of Integers which can represent Current and Max Progress

```
@Override
protected void doInBackground() {
    publishProgress(myValue2, myValue1);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    if (progressDialog.isIndeterminate()) { //optional check
        progressDialog.setMax(values[1]);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    }
    progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Get the context from the progressDialog, cast it as Activity and use runOnUiThread :

```
((Activity)progressDialog.getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressDialog.setMax(myValue1);
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            }
        });
```

**Option 2 :**

Configure onProgressUpdate to set the max value and call publishProgress with appropriate value configuration in doInBackground :

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // use this to set max
        publishProgress(null, maxValue);

        // use this to update progress
        publishProgress(progress);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        final Integer progressValue = values[0];

        if (progressValue == null) {
            // set max
            final Integer maxValue = values[1];
            progressDialog.setMax(maxValue);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        } else {
            // update progress
            progressDialog.setProgress(progressValue);
        }
    }
```